# Orientdb python list databases?

Tags: python, orientdb, pyorient

i am using Python to get a list of databases that were more than 30 days old. So far i have been able to get the list of the databases from [here](https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/pyorient/PyOrient-Client-DB-List.html). And this is my code :-

```
import pyorient

def list_orient_databases(name):
    # Use a breakpoint in the code line below to debug your script.
    print(f'{name}')
    client = pyorient.OrientDB("10.121.3.55", 2525)
    session_id = client.connect("admin", "admin")
    db_names = client.db_list().__getattr__('databases')

    db_count = 0

    for db_name in db_names:
        print(db_name)
```

How can i adjust the code to get list of databases 30 days older or more? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Is there some createDate field on the DB's?  If so you could just add `date_field < currentDate - 30`.  That's just pseudo code but you get the idea

Comment: @JD2775 hmm interesting!! i'll try this out. So this would be an if condition right? `if date_field < currentDate - 30` print(db_name) ?

Comment: Correct.  You'll need to figure out how to access that date field in your code (if it exists) and then do the `if` statement to narrow down your results that you are interested in

Comment: Cool. i would suggest adding this as an answer just in case. If it works, i'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are able to somehow pull a `create_date` value for the DB you could use something like this using the [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) object:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    
d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)

# 'X' would be whatever the database create date name parameter is
for db_name in db_names:
    if db_name['X'] <= d:
        print(db_name)
```

You'll have to adjust this as needed but this gives you a general idea